# Mysql query with group by?

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
Table users :
id      (int)
status  (int)
regdate (datetime)
```

I want to get the results in order of regdate, with count(id) 's and group by status.

For example :

```
 Date           Count(status = 3)    Count(status = 4)   Count(status = 5)
 
2014-02-24            2                   5                     8 
2014-02-25            2                   5                     8
```

**We should have get the results in only a line per day.**

Thanks too much in advance.

Comment: that's called a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them directly. the workarounds are ugly and get EXTREMELY unmaintainable VERY quickly. Fetch the query normally and do the col->row transformation in your client-side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` with condition if there are limited statutes like 3,4,5,the expression in SUM() are evaluated as boolean , for n no. of statutes look at Marc B's comments

```
SELECT
regdate,
SUM(status = 3),
SUM(status = 4),
SUM(status = 5)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY regdate
ORDER BY regdate
```

Comment: @vural can you add the [sql fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of your table definitions and sample dataset